# Filter dropdown in django forms

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-queryset

In forms, I am trying to filter marketplace drop down field that belong to the logged in user based on its group. Its listing all the dropdown field items. I tried below but I think something is wrong with the filter part.

> ```
>  class InfringementForm(ModelForm):
>
>  def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
>  super(InfringementForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
>  self.fields['marketplace'].queryset = 
>  Marketplace.objects.filter(groups__user=self.user)
>
>   class Meta:
>     model = Infringement
> ```

> ```
> class Meta:
>     ordering = ['-updated', '-created']
> def __str__(self):
>     return self.name
> ```
>
> > ```
> >     fields = ['name', 'link', 'infringer', 'player', 'remove', 'status', 
> >        'screenshot','marketplace']
> > ```

models.py

> ```
> class Marketplace (models.Model):
> name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
> updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
> created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
> groups = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1)
> ```

Comment: Also share the view, you need to pass user as `InfrigmentForm(user="some_user_name')` in the view.

Comment: Thanks the drop down is filtered down correctly now after you suggestions. But now I cannot save.                            Field 'id' expected a number but got <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['jpuImOwNeoUc7Lu9ZXsgEs5hc96G9VXXYBRvTvt1SYyDs7lqrlKyhL0n4fVZjHbV'], 'name': ['Neymard'], 'link': ['https://www.mey.com'], 'infringer': ['2'], 'player': ['8'], 'status': ['1'], 'screenshot': [''], 'marketplace': ['2']}>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

final answer is adding self.user = user in the forms and adding user in the view.

forms.py

> ```
>   class InfringementForm(ModelForm):
>   def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
>   self.user = user  
>   super(InfringementForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
>   self.fields['marketplace'].queryset = 
>   Marketplace.objects.filter(groups__user=self.user)
>   class Meta:
>   model = Infringement
>     
>   fields = ['name', 'link', 'infringer', 'player', 'remove', 'status', 
>   'screenshot', 'marketplace']
> ```

views.py

> ```
>  @login_required(login_url='login')
>   def createInfringement(request):
>   user=request.user
>   form = InfringementForm(user=request.user)
>   if request.method == 'POST':
>   
>   form = InfringementForm(user, request.POST, request.FILES)
>   if form.is_valid():
>      
>      form.save()
>   return redirect('home')    context ={'form': form}    return render (request, 'base/infringement_form.html', context)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this inside `__init__()` method:

```py
def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs): 
    self.user = user     
    super(InfringementForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['marketplace'].queryset = Marketplace.objects.filter(groups__user=self.user)
```

Comment: @login_required(login_url='login')
def createInfringement(request):
   form = InfringementForm()
   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = InfringementForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
      if form.is_valid():
         
         form.save()
      return redirect('home')
   context ={'form': form}
   return render (request, 'base/infringement_form.html', context)

Comment: I get an error. Added user=request.user to view .TypeError at /create-infringement/
Field 'id' expected a number but got <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [''], 'name': ['Cristiano Ronaldo'], 'link': ['https://www.mey.com'], 'infringer': ['2'], 'player': ['8'], 'status': ['5'], 'screenshot': [''], 'marketplace': ['6']}>.                                                                 The above exception (int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'QueryDict') was the direct cause of the following exception:

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution...

Basically `groups` is foreign key in `Marketplace` model it returns a full object of the `Group` model.

you tried to filter with the full object it's not possible in a query, so you can filter using `id` of the user instance

#### Code becomes like this

```
class InfringementForm(ModelForm):

 def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
 super(InfringementForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
 self.fields['marketplace'].queryset = 
 Marketplace.objects.filter(groups__user__id=self.user.id)

  class Meta:
    model = Infringement
```